# PowerShell Socket: after 3/4 hours the socket-server blocks totally?

Tags: sockets, powershell

I wrote a socket-client just to send messages to a socket-server (both on the same pc). The to check whether the other side is still 'living' the server sends every now and then a blank.

As the client does not need the blanks from the server it does not read them from the stream, they are ignored.

After 3/4 hors the server was blocked totally. Even ctrl-c does not 'kill' the server. Only after I killed the client the server died immediately.

My question: If I don't read (and empty this way) the incoming stream - the server (which sends the 'ignored' blanks) will block - is that the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried running netstat /b to see if you've gotten all of you sockets stuck in a "CLOSE WAIT" state?

Comment: Werll, I don't think so as neither the client (not emptying the receive buffer) nor the server (writing into that buffer) did close anything.